# Python error installing package

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, importerror

I have just installed python 3.5.1 and i read that pip should be installed by default.

I am trying to install the package: numpy 1.10.2  by using the command: python -m pip install numpy 1.10.2 just as it says in the python documentation, but i get the error: ImportError: No module named site.

I am on windows and writing it in the windows cmd. Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the command

`python -m pip install numpy` (without the version number).

Comment: I still get the same error. Python is in this directory:  C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

So i tried to write C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32/Scripts/pip install numpy, and i do not know why but i think it worked